# Trying to configure a HD 7470/8470 - Strange video refresh Title changeg and instability of video card

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, radeon, catalyst

I've found [BinaryDriverHowto/AMD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD).

New items are in my comments ....

I have got `amd-driver-installer-catalyst-15-20.1046-x86.x86_64.run` in my `Downloads` folder ready to run, but when I'm trying to issue the command `sh amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13-4-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/trusty`, it does not want to run it. I have the error message:

```
sh: 0: Can't open amd-driver-installer-catalyst-15-20.1046-x86.x86_64.run
```

Can someone explain me what to do?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display'; dpkg -l | grep fglrx` terminal command.

Comment: Dorry but I do not hoa to use : fglrx-installer 
fglrx-installer-updates 
fglrx-installer-experimental-9 
fglrx-installer-experimental-12 
fglrx-installer-experimental-13

in the https://goo.gl/8dkIaw document. Manay thanks in advance

Comment: With the  "lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display'; dpkg -l | grep fglrx"  commande i obtain  ; 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos XT [Radeon HD 7470/8470 / R5 235 OEM]
 Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Radeon HD 8470 OEM
 Kernel driver in use: radeon. So what is the next to do. I got many SynologyAssistant-5.2-5566_amd64.deb, fglrx_15.201-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb and fglrx-core_15.201-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb.

Comment: Which is the *.deb file to user please ?

Comment: @pico6 the result  off your command is  ; lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display'; dpkg -l | grep fglrx
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos XT [Radeon HD 7470/8470 / R5 235 OEM]
 Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Radeon HD 8470 OEM
 Kernel driver in use: radeon

Comment: @ David forster : I'av noed this url http://goo.gl/MzKv3Y witch is not applicable in my case

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to download and run any files. You can install 15.20 driver by running in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

This is the correct way of installing the driver.

Comment: What do I have to next please ?  Laurent

Comment: If it installed without errors, then nothing. Reboot and enjoy.

Comment: I must say that in the configuration I have the graphic card is recognized as a AMD Radeon HD 7000 series but I DO have strange behaviours on refresh.

Comment: Many thanks Pilot6 it seems to work now !!! :)

Comment: Ooupsss sorry;  The video card does not seem to react properly. is there a way to switch it back ?

Comment: You can always remove it by `sudo apt-get purge fglrx*`.

Comment: I cannot even access to videos downloads please help !!!!!

Comment: There is not enough information to help. You wanted to install that driver, I gave you a command how to do it. You did not like it for some reason, I gave you a command how to remove it. I do not know where you can't access and how is it related to your question.

Comment: Is there a whay to switch it back to standard Ubuntu detected  detected by the system  during installation process ?

Answer (score 0):

I just do what Pilot6 has recommended and I never have the same drawbacks. It seems to work now and to anyone that contributed.

The solution is  definitely :

*sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates*

Laurent06000

Comment: After having screen flashing sometimes I had to reverse back using http://goo.gl/W8qvzp