# Reducing Chrome GPU CPU usage

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, google-chrome

I read carefully the [Why does chrome use excessive amounts of CPU?](http://goo.gl/UdQ0rU)

But I'm not familiar specifically to the item ;

Switching to integrated GPU solves the high CPU issue for me.

I have the following system:

```
Graphics: 
       Card-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7600G]
               Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8730M]
               Display Server: X.Org 1.17.1 driver: fglrx
               Resolution: 1366x768@60.0hz, 1920x1200@60.0hz
               GLX Renderer: AMD Radeon HD 7600G
               GLX Version: 4.4.13374 - CPC 15.20.1013*
```

My graphics card is a :

```
 lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|Display'; dpkg -l | grep fglrx
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos XT [Radeon HD 7470/8470 / R5 235 OEM]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Radeon HD 8470 OEM
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

Could somebody help me to understand what has been done.

The solution for Chrome discussion [Why is "GPU Process" causing such a high CPU usage with Google Chrome?](https://goo.gl/NcEsGF)
is useless...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dd think  that when issue  http://goo.gl/hyLHgw will be solved I could accelerate the whole thing. thanks any way.

Answer (score 13):

Finally applying the [Why is "GPU Process" causing such a high CPU usage with Google Chrome?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/TVNtsDRGs8U/gnZNdvcdZjUJ)  recommandations is the better answer that I thought at first sight.

With the latest version of google chrome  (v 45.0.2524.99) along with a change of the AMD driver [Trying to configure a HD 7470/8470 - Strange video refresh Title changed and instability of video card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672641/trying-to-configure-a-hd-7470-8470-strange-video-refresh-title-changeg-and-ins)
provides quite good results in my specific case.

The essential part if it is : "*Disabling GPU accelerated canvas 2D*"  (accessed via the "chrome://flags/" command:

[image: screenshot]

Hope this will help for people having CPU overhead with Google Chrome.

Laurent06000